# Set object permissions so that only the user specified in `owner` field can modify the object?

Tags: django

I have a model, `Package`:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    VIP = models.BooleanField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contents = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = # a string, user name goes here
```

For any particular instance of `Package` (that is, each row of the database), I want that only the user whose username matches `owner` can modify this instance, via the admin interface. How can I do this?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.PermissionsMixin

Comment: @Gocht not sure how that solves my problem?

Comment: Can modify the object _how_? In the admin? via the ORM? using web forms? You need to be specific.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist via admin

Comment: That just sounds like normal view logic. When you're processing the form data, at some point you say `if package.owner != request.user` or whatever condition works with how you've set this up, then deny access by returning a templated message politely stating they can't do that. Is there something more complicated going on that I'm missing?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Sorry, I edited my comment. It's not through forms, but through admin interface.

Comment: Try with the view's [dispatch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the [`has_change_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_change_permission) for your model admin.

```
class PackageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj):
        if request.user.is_super_user():
            # allow superusers to edit all packages
            return True
        if obj is None:
            # The docs say that the method should handle obj=None
            # Don't allow user to edit packages in general 
            return False
        # Let the user edit the package if they are the owner.
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

The code above assumes that owner is a foreign key, which I recommend. If you really want to store the username as a string, then you would change the last line to:

```
return obj.owner == request.user.username
```

You could add an extra check to make sure that the user has the 'change' permission for the Package model as well (see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions) for more info).

Note there is a `has_delete_permission` model admin method, which you might want to override as well.

Comment: you mean `return obj.owner == request.user.username`, right?

Comment: Yes, I meant `obj.owner`. Usually, making owner a foreign key to the user model would be better than storing the username as a string.

Comment: Shouldn't `has_change_permission` include a `self` argument?

Comment: Yes, it should. I have added it now.